# how to generate random numbers (probabilities) from exponential distribution that sum up to 1

Tags: r, random, exponential-distribution

Consider I want `x` random numbers that sum up to one and that distribution is exponential. When I use

```
x<-c(10,100,1000)

a<-rexp(x[3],rate=1)

a<-a/sum(a)
```

This will change the distribution, right?

So does anybody know a way so that the probabilities are still exponential distributed? I know that they will then not be completely independent anymore.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normalization changes the distribution and, in fact, it is not possible to achieve precisely what you want.

---

**Straightforward proof**

Let X<sub>1</sub>, …, X<sub>n</sub> for some finite n be random variables whose values you want to generate. The two requirements that you have are

1. X<sub>i</sub>~Exp(λ) for some λ>0 and i=1,…,n.
2. X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub>=1.

While each of the two individual requirements are easy to fulfil, it’s not possible to have both at the same time. The reason for that is that the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Probability_density_function) of an exponential distribution is **positive** on [0,∞). That means that each X<sub>i</sub> attains values greater than 1 with positive probability, which means that the requirement 2 does not always hold. In fact, it holds with zero probability.

---

**Probability distribution implied by the normalization**

Now you propose an intuitive approach to start with the requirement 1 and to perform normalization Z<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>i</sub> / (X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub>) for each i=1,…,n. However, few distributions behave nicely under transformations such as addition, multiplication, and particularly division, because random denominators are rarely tractable. In this case, we have additional complication that the numerator and denominator of Z<sub>i</sub> are dependent.

Nevertheless, the name of the **exact** distribution of Z<sub>i</sub> is actually known and it is the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). To see that, [note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions) X<sub>i</sub>~Gamma(1,λ), where λ acts as the rate parameter. Next, we look at a [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Related_distributions) of the Dirichlet distribution: we start with Y<sub>i</sub>~Gamma(α<sub>i</sub>, θ) for i=1,…,n and then, just like you propose, define W<sub>i</sub>=Y<sub>i</sub> / (Y<sub>1</sub>+…+Y<sub>n</sub>). Then (W<sub>1</sub>,…,W<sub>n</sub>)~Dirichlet(α<sub>i</sub>,…,α<sub>n</sub>). However, in the case of requirement 1, we have that α<sub>i</sub>=1 for each i=1,…,n. Thus, your approach leads to (Z<sub>1</sub>,…,Z<sub>n</sub>)~Dirichlet(1,…,1).

You may then simulate values from it using, e.g., the `MCMCpack` package:

```
library(MCMCpack)
rdirichlet(1, c(1, 1, 1))
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] 0.2088649 0.7444334 0.04670173
sum(rdirichlet(1, c(1, 1, 1)))
# [1] 1
```

Now looking at the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function) of Dirichlet(1,...,1) you can notice that it actually is constant (when positive). So, in a way you may see it as a multivariate uniform one. It makes sense if you think about it for a second (e.g., think if points on x+y=1, x+y+z=1).

The multivariate distribution being somewhat uniform, however, does not imply something similar in terms of marginal distributions. In fact, one can [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_distributions) that they are Beta(1, n-1).

**On Z<sub>i</sub> being restricted to [0,1]**

Since, for certain values of λ, exponential random variables are concentrated close to zero, one may falsely think that they actually have a bounded support.

The cumulative distribution function of X<sub>i</sub>~Exp(λ) is 1-exp(-λx). So then P(X<sub>i</sub><=1)=1-exp(-λ) which is 1 only in the limit as λ->∞, but in that case X converges to 0 in distribution. So, we cannot have a nondegenerate exponential random variable restricted to [0,1]. Notice, though, that for large fixed values of λ 1-exp(-λ) is close to 1 and one may falsely think that X<sub>i</sub> is actually restricted to [0,1].

A couple of trivial demonstrations. First, Z<sub>i</sub> (following the Dirichlet distribution) are restricted to [0,1].

```
data <- replicate({
  x <- rexp(5)
  z <- x[1] / sum(x)}, n = 100000)
range(data)
# [1] 1.060492e-06 9.633081e-01
plot(density(data, bw = 0.01))
```

[image]

Second, X~Exp(1) clearly takes values above 1.

```
x <- rexp(10000)
range(x)
# [1] 7.737341e-05 1.005980e+01
mean(x < 1)
# [1] 0.6391
plot(density(x))
```

[image]

---

**Scaling by a positive factor**

There were multiple comments proposing to use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions) that the exponential distribution is closed under scaling by a positive factor so that if X ~ Exp(λ), then kX ~ Exp(λ/k). That certainly is true, but it’s not applicable in the current case. The reason is that k = X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub> is not a constant (meaning that k is different for different realizations of X<sub>i</sub>) and, for this reason, kX ~ Exp(λ/k) does not hold. Now if we considered k as a constant (e.g., 5), then there would be no guarantee that Z<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>i</sub> / 5 will satisfy your requirement 2. In fact, the constraint would hold with probability 0.

To have a clear understanding of what's happening and not to be misled by empirical "proofs" of @MauritsEvers, here are some more details.

Let (Ω,F,P) be the probability space. Then X<sub>i</sub>:Ω->R; i.e., X<sub>i</sub> is a function taking values X<sub>i</sub>(ω) in R, with outcomes ω (imagine them as `set.seed` values) from Ω. Now we indeed have this property that, for a constant k, kX<sub>i</sub>~Exp(λ/k). By constant, however, it is meant that regardless of the realized outcome ω from Ω, the value of k is always the same, as if k:Ω->R was a constant function. What @MauritsEvers proposes is k = X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub>. That, however, seen as a function, is not constant, and depends on the outcome ω.

Some trivial examples demonstrating how this logic fails are the following: let k=1/X<sub>i</sub>. Then kX<sub>i</sub>=1, which is a degenerate random variable, not an exponential one. Similarly, if X~N(0,1), then kX=1 and not kX~N(0,1/X^2), which would "follow" from the fact that X~N(0,1) gives kX ~ N(0,k^2) for a **constant** k.

---

**Erroneous logic**

Now the origin of this erroneous logic described above could be said to be mishandling probabilistic concepts + dealing directly with simulated values in R. @MauritsEvers claims that if we run

```
n <- 3
x <- rexp(n)
k <- sum(x)
```

then the realized sum `k` can be used as the constant k mentioned above and to expect that kX<sub>i</sub>~Exp(?). Sanity check of taking `n <- 1`, as in the example above, already shows that there is something wrong with this kind of argument since then `x / k` is simply `1` — a degenerate random variable, not an exponential one. It is claimed that `k <- sum(x)` is a valid choice because it is a number of already observed realizations. That actually is the reason why this choice is invalid. In the notation from before, we have k(ω) = X<sub>1</sub>(ω)+…+X<sub>n</sub>(ω) so that k is not a constant function.

Another way to look at it is that, if we see `x` as somehow random, then `k` is *just as random* as it is the sum of `x`. Now both `x` and `k` are numbers, realizations, but we know neither of their values before we ask R to print them. A definition of a constant k would be that we always know its value, regardless of ω or `set.seed`.

Lastly, as an undergraduate exercise, one may consider looking at the CDF of kX<sub>i</sub>:

P(kX<sub>i</sub> <= x) = P(X<sub>i</sub> <= x/k) = 1-exp(-λx/k)

and hence kX<sub>i</sub>~Exp(λ/k), as expected. Now take `n <- 2`. In that case we are dealing with

P(X<sub>1</sub> / (X<sub>1</sub> + X<sub>2</sub>) <= x)

and we no longer can get rid of the complicated denominator so easily. Surely we can define a constant k = X<sub>1</sub>(ω)+…+X<sub>n</sub>(ω) for some fixed ω from Ω. But then Z<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>i</sub> / (X<sub>1</sub>(ω)+…+X<sub>n</sub>(ω)) are no longer restricted to [0,1] and requirement 2 fails again.

---

**False empirical "proofs"**

Lastly, one may ask, why does the empirical “proof” of @MauritsEvers partially (since simulation + fitting + hypothesis testing is far from a theoretical proof) claims that Z<sub>i</sub> actually do follow an exponential distribution.

A crucial element of this “proof” was to take `lambda <- 1` and `n <- 1000`, a relatively large value. In that case we have that

Z<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>i</sub>/(X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub>) ≈ X<sub>i</sub> / n * n / (X<sub>1</sub>+…+X<sub>n</sub>).

The second term on the right hand side, by the law of large numbers, goes to λ — a fixed number — while the first term follows, as we know, Exp(λn). So, for a large n we get an **approximation** of Z<sub>i</sub> as λExp(λn). However, the original question is not about approximations or limiting distributions.

---

**Summary**

We may distinguish the following three cases:

1. Small n. (Z<sub>1</sub>, …, Z<sub>n</sub>) follows the Dirichlet(1,…,1) distribution and the marginal distributions are not equivalent to the exponential ones. Approximating them by exponential ones gives arbitrary poor results.
2. Large n. (Z<sub>1</sub>, …, Z<sub>n</sub>) still follows the Dirichlet(1,…,1) distribution and the marginal distributions still are not equivalent to the exponential ones. Approximating them by exponential ones should give perfectly valid results for practical purposes, however.
3. Limiting case when n->∞. As n grows, each Z<sub>i</sub> gets closer and closer to λExp(λn). However, as we saw, λExp(λn) tends to a degenerate random variable identically equal to zero.

Comment: one additional question. when all alpha for the Dirichlet are 1, would this not lead to a uniform distribution in the end?

Comment: one additional question. how do I get the marginal distribution from the Dirichlet especially when all alpha are 1, does this simply mean all random draws are unique?

Comment: @JmO, I updated my answer a little. The "uniformness" of the joint distribution and non-uniformness of the marginals is an interesting thing to discuss, but surely not programming-related, so I didn't go into details anymore.. And yes, if I understand you correctly, all the draws are "unique". In fact, any specific draw has probability zero. So, after observing a certain vector, the probability of observing it again is zero.

Answer (score 0):

From `?rexp`

> ```
> rexp(n, rate = 1)
>    [...]
>    n: number of observations. If ‘length(n) > 1’, the length is
>       taken to be the number required.
> ```

So

```
x<-c(10,100,1000)
a<-rexp(x,rate=1)
```

is the same as

```
rexp(3, rate = 1)
```

Normalising it to 1 ensures that the (exponential) probability function satisfies the criteria of an (exponential) probability density function.

---

### Update

Following the somewhat obscure discussion with @JuliusVainora, I will demonstrate that `a` is indeed exponentially distributed.

1. Let's re-generate the data:

   ```
   x <- c(10, 100, 1000)
   set.seed(2018)
   a <- rexp(x[3], rate=1)
   a <- a / sum(a)
   ```

   I'm using a fixed random seed here for reproducibility.
2. I'll fit a Bayesian exponential model to estimate `lambda` based on `a` using `rstan`

   ```
   library(rstan)
   stan_code <- "
   data {
       int N;
       real x[N];
   }

   parameters {
       real lambda;
   }

   model {
       x ~ exponential(lambda);
   }
   "

   fit <- stan(
       model_code = stan_code,
       data = list(N = length(a), x = a))

   fit
   #Inference for Stan model: b690462e8562075784125cf0e71c81e2.
   #4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1;
   #post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.
   #
   #          mean se_mean    sd    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5% n_eff Rhat
   #lambda 1000.21    0.80 31.11  941.86  978.74  998.95 1020.84 1062.97  1502    1
   #lp__   5907.27    0.02  0.66 5905.52 5907.09 5907.53 5907.71 5907.75  1907    1
   #
   #Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Sun Nov  4 01:09:40 2018.
   #For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
   #and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split chains (at
   #convergence, Rhat=1).
   ```
3. We perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare the empirical distribution of `a` with that of an exponential distribution with `lambda` estimated from the previous Stan model

   ```
   ks.test(a, "pexp", summary(fit)$summary[1, 1])
   #
   #   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
   #
   #data:  a
   #D = 0.021828, p-value = 0.7274
   #alternative hypothesis: two-sided
   ```

   With a *p*-value of 0.72 we *fail* to reject the null hypothesis of samples being drawn from two *different* distributions.

---

### Update 2

To clear up a discussion in the comments:

1. It's [straightforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85554/is-the-family-of-exponential-distributions-closed-under-scaling) (and a lot more transparent IMO) to demonstrate that the family of exponential distributions is closed under scaling by a positive factor *without* having to invoke the whole measure-theoretic machinery.
2. More importantly, let's recall that any probability density function is defined as

   ```
   phi(x) = p(x) * N
   ```

   where

   ```
   N = int p(x)
   ```

   with the integral being taken over the sample space of `p(x)` such that

   ```
   int phi(x) = 1.
   ```

   Yup, that's the same `p(x)` in both the expression for `phi` and for `N`. Here comes the important part: **`N` is still a constant as we sum (integrate) over the entire sample space.**

Equivalently, we normalise samples drawn from an exponential distribution by the **constant** sum of the (already) drawn samples.

Comment: sry I edited the question as I forgot to index the x, I wanted to create random numbers with n =10, n=100, n=100. for simplicity consider x = 1000 only.

Comment: I thought that a/sum(a) will make it rather gamma distributed than exponential but I want these to stay exponentially distributed

Comment: @JmO No, you are drawing 1000 samples from an exponential distribution. Following normalisation those 1000 samples are still exponentially distributed. In more mathematical terms: The (family of) exponential functions is closed under scaling by a positive factor.

Comment: also `plot(a, a/sum(a))`

Comment: Why don't you "demonstrate" the same with `x <- 1`? This is no proof of anything other than similarity in terms of shapes. My answer does contain *theoretical* arguments. If approximations are satisfactory for the OP, then that's a different talk.

Comment: @JuliusVainora ??? I think you're missing the point here. Fitting an exponential model based on one single observation is quite nonsensical and doesn't seem to be relate to OPs original question. I am demonstrating here here that `a` as stated by OP is exponentially distributed. This has nothing to do with approximations. I have already given *theoretical* reasons (that of the exponential distribution being scale invariant); the very *practical* justification is given in this post. If you want to dismiss hypothesis testing (which has nothing to do with approximations) then that's your call.

Comment: I am suggesting to simulate however many i.i.d. cases with `x <- 1` and to do the fitting then.

Comment: I think "*similarity in terms of shapes.*" is slightly misleading. A linear transformation does not change the shape of the distribution - they are the same not similar.

Comment: @JuliusVainora Downvote acknowledged;-) This doesn't make your fallacious "clarification" any more correct unfortunately. I'm curious. Why invoke the big measure-theoretic "fluff"? It doesn't even help with your own point you're trying to force across.

Comment: I am not really into statistics, this is why I ask, but might it be that this is helpful for the discussion? from wikipedia: If Xi ~ Exp(λ) then the sum X1 + ... + Xk = {\displaystyle \sum _{i}X_{i}} \sum _{i}X_{i} ~ Erlang(k, λ) which is just a Gamma(k, λ−1) (in (k, θ) parametrization) or Gamma(k, λ) (in (α,β) parametrization) with an integer shape parameter k. so that with a/sum(a) we create the ratio of an exponential and a gamma distribution? so we need to think if this leads to a exponential distribution or not

Comment: @JmO, that is indeed relevant. In light of MauritsEvers' answer, sum X1 + ... + Xk would be just a constant, though, and there's nothing to do. The truth is that, as I added to my answer, that this ratio follows the Dirichlet distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Related_distributions). In that case, it matters how many draws, k, you have. If k is large, then doing what you do is a really good approximation, although theoretically those shares still do not follow the exponential distribution...

Comment: .. so, 1) low k - poor approximation, Dirichlet distribution, 2) large k - good approximation, Dirichlet distribution, 3) k->∞ does indeed give exponentially distributed shares.

Comment: I'm afraid the KS test is flawed here. See `hist(replicate(5000,{a<-rexp(1000,rate=1); a<-a/sum(a); ks.test(a,"pexp",1000)$p.value}))`. The sample of 1000 being forced to have sum 1 forces the mean to 1/1000. If these were from an exponential distribution, the rate parameter would have to be 1000. Under the null hypothesis the p-values of the KS-test should be uniformly distributed. Here they are not. Test is biased by the procedure.

Comment: @A.Webb the estimated rate parameter *is* 1000, see the Stan results for `lambda`. I don’t follow your logic why the KS would be biased here.

Comment: @A.Webb In the KS test above we test the empirical distribution based on `a` against the cumulative distribution function of an exponential function with `lambda = 1000` (estimated from the Stan model, see my code above). We fail to reject the null hypothesis stating that samples being drawn come from the same distribution. I don't know what flaw or bias you are referring to (other than perhaps the usual criticism towards hypothesis testing in general).

Comment: Not a dig at NHT. When the null hypothesis is true, the p-values should be uniformly distributed. Here, they are biased away from 0 (don't reject). Compare the suggestion in my comment above to `hist(replicate(5000,{a<-rexp(1000,rate=1000); ks.test(a,"pexp",1000)$p.value}))` to see the difference. The point that the normalized sample is "close" to exponential when the normalized sample is large is true, but the test used here is biased by having the mean match for free. [Brief mention at Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Test_with_estimated_parameters).

Comment: @A.Webb interesting. I wasn’t aware of such a bias. Thanks for the clarification.